# Process not running if tooltip open

Tags: c#, winforms, process, tooltip

I have a function that checks to see if a given process is running and it works except for when that process has a tooltip open. If the process does have a tooltip open then this function returns false and i can't seem to figure out the problem.

```
public static bool isRunning(string progName, bool isId, int id)
{
    foreach (Process pro in Process.GetProcesses("."))
        if (isId)
        {
            if (pro.Id == id)
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (pro.ProcessName == progName)
                return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```

An example of calling this function - isRunning("chrome.exe", false, -1) **or** isRunning("", true, 248).
Is there something I am doing wrong or something else i need to check for?

Here is the full code for the file: http://ideone.com/9CUJ5V

**EDIT**: I partially solved my issue. I added this:

```
foreach(Process pro in Process.GetProcessesByName(progName)){
    if(pro.MainWindowHandle != (IntPtr)0)
        return true;
```

According to the msdn Documentation on [Process.MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx), it will return zero if it does not have a graphical interface.

But the next issue is, for example, if I am running steam minimized to the taskbar (so no window actually visible), it returns true.

Comment: Indeed after reading your post again, my comment is not applicable.

Then I think that a process that is waiting for closing of the popup is not considered 'Running'.

You may have to check some other System.Diagnostics classes and methods, like GetProcessesByName, to also get non-running process info.

Comment: Alrite well ill try that tomorrow and ill report back here and tell ya if it works with some additional checks.

Comment: @Pieter21 I have pertially fixed it but I have a new problem now...